# MobaXterm and GIT plugin

Tags: git, plugins, ssh

I am using MobaXterm for remote everything.
All is nice, it is really good software and I can do almost all what I want to do from my Windows on my servers.

But I have a problem using git.

I have tried the git plugin from MobaXterm website and I get an error when I want to clone a https repository (/usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-ftp.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory).

I also try  the command apt-get install git. I have also the same type of error.

Did anybody knows how to fix it, as I really want to conitnue using MobaXterm ?

Thanks guy

Answer (score 4):

It seems that this issue is due to an obsolete version of libopenssl (not in line with this up to date version of openssl).

You should try to upgrade this library by running:

```
apt-get install libopenssl100
```